# Anyone knows this Star Wars model? Grey and dark red with axles for side modules

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

[image]

Got this from a yard sale and now looking for the building instructions.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely [75039-1: V-Wing Starfighter](http://brickset.com/sets/75039-1/V-Wing-Starfighter):

[image: set image]

Instructions (2 different copies, US and EU):

- [6079505](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6079505.pdf)
- [6079506](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6079506.pdf)

Comment: The different versions are to support A4 or "US Letter" sizes - "Building instructions labeled "NA" or "V39" may be printed on US standard letter size paper, building instructions labeled "IN" or "V29" may be printed on EU standard A4 paper" - in this case 505 is the A4, while 506 is the letter size.